# Warning: include

Tags: php

When I execute my php file I get the following error:

> Warning: include(C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs_lib\htmlfunctions.inc)
>   [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\login.php on line 33

```
 define ( "SYSDIR", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs" );
 define ( "CONTENTDIR", SYSDIR. "\\".CONTENTDIR_NAME );
```

I have placed the htmlfuntions.inc file at the same location as shown. What shall I do now?

Comment: You should start by including the relevant code in your question

Comment: here is my code:

define ( "SYSDIR", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs" );
 
 define ( "CONTENTDIR", SYSDIR. "\\".CONTENTDIR_NAME );

Comment: I hate to not be constructive here but... 0_o

Comment: We disagree in what we consider relevant code. The error message complaints about an `include` statement on line 33. Your code does not have any `include` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try and crack this.

In this file you are trying to include `htmlfunctions.inc`

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\login.php
```

This is where it's looking

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs_lib\htmlfunctions.inc
```

Simply put. Does `..\htdocs_lib` exist? If so, is `htmlfuntions.inc` a file in that folder?